# Angular custom validator not firing when input untouched?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-custom-validators

I have a reactive form as following:

```js
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  email: ['', this.customValidator()]
});
```

I also have a "submit" button with a `[disabled]` condition:

```html
<button [disabled]="form.invalid" (click)="create()">Create</button>
```

If `email` input is untouched and I modify `name` input, **`customValidator` is not fired** and `Create` button enables despite the `customValidator()` would return an error.

On the other hand, the `name` control has a `Validators.required` validation that is fired even if the input is untouched, which is the desired behaviour.

> [Example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-validator-dzmdoz?file=src/app/app.component.ts): I want the `email` input to be required
> (and the create button to be disabled) when `name` has value on it even if `email` is untouched.

Comment: It should work as it is. Post an MRE or a demo for us to be able to debug. Here is something to begin with: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-validator-n6bxmg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Can you add some stackblitz to this, since Vega is right, this should work

Comment: Can you share the code of your custom validator?

Comment: MRE is [mre] , FYI

Comment: @Bozhinovski stackblitz added

Comment: @Vega stackblitz added

Comment: @TsvetanGanev stackblitz added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this solution. Instead of abstratcontrol I've used FormControl which is much easier to handle. Also you can pass the parent-child param to the custom validator as seen on this example:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', this.customVal('name')], -> you can pass the value here
    });
  }
```

Please check the stackblitz for complete solution.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-validator-uhhicz?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Still enabling Create button when only filling `name` input

Comment: @Iñigo its fixed now. Please check it out

Comment: what was the solution? its still not working as you can see here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-validator-mwz3sg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts%3AL35,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html
if you try to save the form its valid even if the fields are not the same (I've changed the validator)

Answer (score 1):

Found a couple ways for solving the problem:

#### 1 Angular cross-validation.

The custom validator is applied to the `FormGroup` and not to the `FormControl`. The validation is executed every time the form is modified.

```js
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  email: ['']
}, { validators: this.customValidator});
```

#### 2 Subscribe to form valueChanges + updateValueAndValidity.

```js
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  email: ['', this.customValidator()]
});
```

And on ngOnInit, whenever the form changes, the validation is executed:

```js
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
    this.form.get('email').updateValueAndValidity();
})
```

Comment: That is indeed the case, cross-validation solves the behavior problem, but that should not mark email input in red if you just click on it and then focus out. From user's perspective that only work if email is never required. It does not make much sense to disable button if email input is empty but not mark it as invalid, how are u supposed to understand that button is disabled because you have not introduced email?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, this.customVal()]],
    });
  }
```

Comment: I don't want it to be required always, the custom validator logic is just an example to demonstrate that the validation is only fired when touched.

Answer (score 0):

As Iñigo say, a FormControl only is "validate" if is modify the input or if you call manually to "updateValueAndValidity".

So another way is subscribe to form.get('name').valueChange (not forget unsubscribe)

```
this.form.get('name').valueChange.subscribe(_=>{
  this.form.get('email').updateValueAndValidity()
})
```

Or we can use input event in .html

```
<input formControlName="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" 
      (input)="form.get('email').updateValueAndValidity()" />
```